# Why does my Selenium webdriver instance not apply the options specified?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to apply some options to my selenium webdriver instance. However, the options `add_argument` are not applied when testing my script:

```
    # Set service parameter for the driver
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    # Add options
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": "/Users/jonas/Desktop/cherrypicks/screenshots",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    })

    # Initiate driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

The `experimental_option` settings work though.

Comment: ` options.add_argument("--start-maximized")` did selenium launch the browser in full screen ?

Comment: @cruisepandey no..

Comment: Strange what is the version you are on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out:
[Chrome-flags](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md#--enable-automation)

`disable-infobars` is removed. You may have to `enable-automation` instead, but please go through the information provided before applying it, as it may disable some features that might not be suitable for automation.

`start-maximized` works as I tested it.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!